# Implementing theme in angular2

Tags: css, angular, styles, less, components

I am trying to implement theming in Angular2 project.

When someone change theme of web app, it will change the class of body using javascript. And each component in an application has relevant colors for each theme.

Can someone suggest me how to do this in Angular2 components.

when I write my component stylesheet with

```
body.theme-1 .header {
   background-color: red;
}
```

it doesn't work.

Any other way to implement this.

If I cut same css from component stylesheet and put in to index.html or common stylesheet, it works. But it is a huge application and I don't want to write all component styles in to once place. Not manageable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found answer from Angular2 documentation.

You can use :host-context() function

```
:host-context(.theme-1) .header {
    background-color: red;
}
```

It works like a charm.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html

Check above link for further information

Answer (score 6):

If you declare `ViewEncapsulation.none` in your component the styles from that component will apply globally to your application.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'style-test',
  template: `<div> Global stylesheet</div>`,
  styles: ['body {
                  background: blue;
                 }'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // Use to 
                                       //disable CSS 
                                      //Encapsulation 
                                     //for this component
})
export class SecondComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JS_astronauts, this works but it loose the component encapsulation. I used :host-context() (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html). You can still have encapsulation

Comment: If you add CSS to your index.html directly, you don't need to disable view encapsulation. Such styles are not rewritten by Angular2 and are applied to all elements in your page (except when `ViewEncapsulation.Native` is used in browsers with native shadow DOM support)